# How can I log what is going wrong in my controller

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to register a user on my website with the laravel/vue.js/vuex. In my store actions, I'm calling the tryRegister action to post a request. But it keeps responding with a 401 error not authorizaed, and I don't understand why. So I made my controller as basic as it can get to just get a response and even then it keeps throwing the 401 authorization error. I'm new to back-end developing and just can't understand why this happens. I do know for sure that the route is working. How can I make my controller function give a basic response to see if it is working? And why is it giving an authorization error even tho I'm not doing anything with authorization, is that just the standard error a controller gives?

Try register action

```
tryRegister(context, credentials) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios
            .post("/api/auth/register", credentials)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
                //context.commit("registerSucces", response.data);
                resolve(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error.response);
                reject(error);
            });
    });
}
```

Authorization controller register function

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    // $user = User::create([
    //     'email'    => $request->email,
    //     'password' => $request->password,
    // ]);

    //$token = auth('api')->login($user);

    //return $this->respondWithToken($token);


    return response()->json(['message' => 'controller register']);
}
```

Comment: check whether you used a `auth` middleware  in your route on in the controller's constructor method.

Comment: Do you have a token for the route? Is there a middleware? Is the route protected in some way(possibly behind a firewall - I assume laravel has some sort of firewall in place)?

Comment: @zahidhasanemon I do have a auth middleware in the constructor. It says `$this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login']]);` so I assume it doesn't do authorization for the login function, so I assume I wouldn't want it for the register. But how could I make an axios call so that it passes the middleware? Or does that depend on the type of middleware?

Comment: I'm currently reading this https://www.cloudways.com/blog/controllers-middleware-laravel/ to understand the middleware better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your register method of the controller is not accessible because of the `auth` middleware. so you are getting not authorized error. make it accessible without authorization. in the constructor method of the controller change this line like below.

```
$this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);
```

> `login` and `register` are controller's method which will be now accessible without authorization.